# Conversion 2d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, 2d

We have an array

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
```

and looking for array:

```
b = [[1, 4, 7],[2, 5, 8],[3, 6, 9]]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with numpy.transpose(). See below:

import numpy as np

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]

[list(i) for i in np.array(a).transpose()]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```